# Add image in profile - "web" does not expect UTF-8 characters

Tags: bug, images, profile-picture, uploader

I tried changing my profile image using the "web" method with the following URL:

http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/22/Habit_de_Mar%C3%AAchal.jpg

It was denied, saying it was the wrong format, because of the URL encoding. Downloading the file and renaming it allowed me to upload the file.

Comment: The same error occurs when trying to use the image uploader for a question or answer, but _not_ the one in chat.

Comment: The word you're looking for is *accept*, not *except*.

Comment: Or maybe *expect* @TRiG.

Comment: Hmm. I've seen *except*/*accept* confusion quite often, and I suspect that *accept* was intended in this case. However, *expect* works reasonably well, I suppose. No harm either way.